How to insert another row in power bi matrix visual?
I have a matrix visual in power bi and would like to insert a "calculated row" at the bottom of the matrix. It would be simply an average calculation. Any tips?
Uploaded a photo about a generated excel table for clarify

Here is the example table:




1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12




BMW














X3
1203
2807
1280
3858
2153
2405
3872
2993
2132
2351
1689
2270


X6
4187
1188
2963
3881
3410
2460
4568
4373
4082
1672
2171
1476


330i
1326
1592
4261
2829
2568
3831
1530
4897
4273
3401
1654
1434


M2 Coupe
1819
2104
2642
4388
3804
1442
1648
2424
4775
1404
4292
2131


Audi














A8
4948
1694
2191
4751
3013
3939
1010
4824
1731
1382
4355
4474


A3
1189
3590
4906
3075
2604
3995
3993
3730
2171
4180
1546
1532


Q7
4854
3590
4385
3800
2353
3541
4309
2091
2483
2107
4468
1995


Mercedes














Benz CLS
3226
2821
2767
1992
2303
1044
2317
3332
4195
2982
4237
3052


Cabriolet
4096
1523
1279
1454
1665
1358
3826
4718
2725
1693
1583
2622


AMG GT
2967
2500
3831
2118
2388
3905
3685
1374
1436
1059
2141
1929


Monthly Rating
2981.5
2340.9
3050.5
3214.6
2626.1
2792
3075.8
3475.6
3000.3
2223.1
2813.6
2291.5




DId you try to activate Row subtotals on your matrix?

I know the post is a bit old by 5 months, but in case you have calculated fields you want to add as rows in a Matrix, you might add those ones in the values field of the visual and then go to "Format Visual" panel then under "Values"/"Options", activate "Switch values to rows"
Screenshot --> https://i.sstatic.net/GZbd8aQE.png

You can do something like this:

put the car brand in the rows of a matrix
put the car model under the brand in the rows of the matrix
put the months in the columns
put the values in the values section of the matrix and use the average as the aggregation


Then, in the format section, you need to enable the "Row subtotal" and the "Apply settings to" "Per row level".

Then you need to disable the Show subtotal for the "model rows".

This only works if you need to average all the data; if you instead need to sum the value and then the average only for the total, you need to write some DAX.
The result will be something like this:

Hope it helps.
